# ParametricPlot cutting off plots

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1**

---

I have some code to plot a parametric function:

```
H1 = 4;
F = Function[x, If[x != 0, (1 - Tanh[H1 x]/(H1 x))/x^2, 25/3]];
x = Function[{r, t}, (1-r + 3 F[1-r] t) (F[1-r]/F[1-r + 3 F[1-r] t])^(-1/3)];
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{x[r, y], y}, {r, Range[-4, 0, .5]}]], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

It clearly works and evaluates the plots just fine, in the entire range `{y, 0, 10}`, however when I try for more values, these first lines suddenly get chopped off:

```
ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Table[{x[r, y], y}, {r, Range[-4, 4, .5]}]], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Evaluating `x` manually works just fine, so I don't understand the problem. Curiously, making the parameter `H1` larger makes the problem worse. I can `Show` plots that I generate separately for different ranges of `r`, but that seems incredibly silly. Mathematica doesn't give me any errors!? What is going on?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. All I can think of is that you have some old definitions kicking around. Have you tried clearing everything or restarting the kernel?

Comment: Your code works in version 11.1. What version are you using?

Comment: @aardvark2012, yep, tried :(

Comment: @Hugh, I'm using 11.0. Uggh, another plotting bug

Comment: I happen to still have version 11.0 and this replicates your problem. So a bug fixed in version 11.1. Not sure how to record this as a bug.

Comment: Yeah, not sure. Thanks very much anyway!

Comment: As others said, it works in 11.1.1. I do see the problem in 11.0.1, and I was not able to find an easy fix with some quick experimentation. As a workaround you could generate the points with a `Table` and plot the result with `ListPlot` (instead of a the more convenient `ParametricPlot`).

Comment: @Szabolcs I just removed [tag:version-11] and noticed after that you had added it right before me.  This surprises me as we are following [your recommendation](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1364/121) not to use tags in this manner.  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It was a mental glitch (I could not explain why I added it, but I can see that I did). Thanks for removing it!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the use of `Evaluate`, if you just remove it then it works fine, you just need to compromise on having a single color plot.

```
ParametricPlot[Table[{x[r, y], y}, {r, Range[-4, 4, .5]}], {y, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks